How many steps are needed to display at least 100 digits on a 4-functions calculator?
Inspired by this great question and its answers we had the privilege to contemplate on Mathematics.SE

Suppose that at the beginning there is a blank calculator and you choose to write a digit, let us say "$9$". In the following, three operations are considered:

Insert the digit "$9$" (or another one, though I believe it will be directly suboptimal)
Add a "$\times$ (times)" symbol (or a "$+$ (plus) symbol", though I also doubt it will be necessary)
Compute the result, that is, press "$=$ (enter)"

The following rules for each step aim to replicate the behavior of a simple 4-functions calculator which has no limit on the number of digits or symbols that can be displayed (i.e., the calculator can easily display any number of digits):

Step 1. Can always be done, except just after step 3
Step 2. Can only be done if there is no other symbol ($\times$) displayed
Step 3.

If done after step 1., it computes the result (enter)
If done after step 2., it copies the first to the second operand. (For example, doing [$9$] [$\times$] [$=$] gives 81.)
If done after step 3., it applies the previous operation to the current result



How many steps do you need to display at least 100 digits? Is the general case $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ solvable?

This question has been improved thanks to the relevant comments of @K. Jiang
Example of valid steps

Initilisation $9$
Step 1 $99$
Step 1 $999$
Step 2 $999\times $
Step 3 $999\times 999 = 998,001$ (6 digits displayed)
Step 2 $998,001\times$
Step 1 $998,001\times9$
Step 1 $998,001\times99$
Step 3 $998,001\times99 = 98,802,099$ (8 digits displayed)
Step 2 $98,802,099\times$
Step 3 $98,802,099\times 98,802,099 = 9,761,854,766,805,801
$ (16 digits displayed)
Step 3 $9,761,854,766,805,801\times 98,802,099 = 3,727,199,664,757,933,739
$ (19 digits displayed)


"Simple calculators" do not work like this (at least not the ones I have used). Once the result is displayed, you can't "concatenate" digits to it (pressing digit buttons is effectively like doing [C] first). And, it is possible to repeatedly press [=] (without respecifying operands); what it does is apply the previous operation to the current result.

In fact, in simple calculators, it is even possible to press [=] immediately after an operation; e.g., [x]; what it does is copy the first to the second operand. (For example, doing [6] [x] [=] gives 36.)

@K.Jiang, I have improved the question thanks to your comments and also acknowledged you :)

I did not mean for you to completely update your post; you gave a nice example and your question was clear. I just meant that the operation of your calculator is perhaps different than the ones I've used before ;). If you are trying to replicate the operation of a standard 4-function calculator, then the edit is fine. But I would still try to include an example similar to your previous one as well as your question at the end.

@K.Jiang, thank you for your comment :) I have added an example!

Do you need to hit exactly $100$ digits, or is it also fine to exceed it?

@K.Jiang, question again improved thanks to you :)

Nice question! I think you should be able to convince yourself that with these rules, the way to get the fastest growth in the long run is by alternately hitting [x] and [=]; i.e., something like <string of digits><string of [x][=]><optional [=]>. What this does is first square your initial number (let's call it $p$), giving $p^2$, then square that (giving $p^4$), then square that  (giving $p^8$), and so on. With every sequence of [x][=], your exponent of $p$ is doubling. The number after $n$ sets of [x][=] is therefore $a_n = p^{2^n}$.
The question then remains as to how long the initial digit string should be to maximize growth to, say, $100$ digits. For this, we might consider for any given number of keypresses, what the largest number we can reach is. For $1$ press, it is obviously just $9$. For $2$ presses, it is $99$. For $3$, it is $999$, and for $4$, it is $9999$. For $5$, we can do [9][9][9][x][=] to get $998001$, and for $6$, we can do [9][9][9][x][=][=] to get $997002999$. Now, for $7$ or more keypresses, the exponent-doubling trick discussed above can be applied. The question is what the "base" number should be. I have found (and perhaps you can verify) that for odd numbers of total presses, $9999$ is the best base, while for even numbers of total presses, $999$ is the best base; the idea is to enter the base, repeat the sequence [x][=] until only one press remains, then do a final [=].
With $13$ presses, the highest number that can be reached with this method is $\approx 9.976 \times 10^{95}$; this is a $96$-digit number, so not quite there. With $\boxed{14}$ presses, you can get up to $\approx 9.531 \times 10^{143}$.
For even numbers of keypresses, the base-$10$ exponent for the numbers achieved in this way go approximately as $(9) \left( 2^{\frac{1}{2} n - 3} \right)$. For odd numbers of keypresses, the base-$10$ exponents go approximately as $(6) \left( 2^{\frac{1}{2} (n + 1) - 3} \right)$. So, given an arbitrary number of desired digits $m$, you can use these to approximate the number of required keypresses.
